# Lambda Expressions for Higher Order Function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, lambda-calculus

Following [this book](https://haskellbook.com/), everything in Haskell is `λ`-calculus: A function like `f(x)=x+1` can be written in Haskell as `f = \x -> x+1` and , in `λ` expression as `λx.x+1`.

- What is `λ` expression for a higher order function like `map::(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`? Or `λ` expression for the function `($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b`?
- What about the list of functions (ie. `f::[a->b]`)? A specific example can be `h = map (\f x -> f x 5) [(-),(+)]`. Then `λ` notation is something like `h = map (λfx.f(x(5)) [(λab.a-b),(λab.a+b)]`?

I'm just familiar with processes like alpha conversion, beta reduction but if you break down the function list in  `λ` terms, that would be appreciated and no need of simplification.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you representing lists in your lambda calculus?

Comment: `$ = \f -> \x -> f x` becomes `λf.λx.f(x)`. It's literally just a different syntax for the same thing.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but when you write `λf.λx.f(x)`, it means a function that returns `f(x)`? While `($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b` takes in a function `λx. termsOf(x)` and returns another function or `λx. termsOf(x)` ?

Comment: > How are you representing lists in your lambda calculus?
I guess a function list is a list of lambda? So it would be `[λ... . ..., λ ... . ....]? Not sure I understand what you're asking. Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: No, same as in haskell, the outer lambda returns another lambda. And yes, `f` is a function.

Comment: I mean lists in general. You're asking how to implement `map`, but you're not saying how your lists are represented as data. Are you using abstract data types like in Haskell, with `::` and `[]` as constructors?

Comment: Abstract datatypes only predefine type constructors and destructors. In particular `::` and `[]` is syntactic sugar for two constants `cons :: α → [α] → [α]` and `nil :: [α]`. The list `[1,2,3]` is just a term `1::2::3::[]` or with even less syntactic sugar `cons(1, cons(2, cons(3, nil)))`.

Comment: In untyped lambda calculus, a higher-order function is just a function, as you can't say anything about what any particular variable represents; everything is encoded in terms of how applications of abstractions relate to each other. Typed lambda calculus is another matter.

Comment: Untyped lambda calculus also has the Y combinator to express recursion - in works a little bit in System Fω (which is Haskell's type system, afaik - it's certainly not simply typed lambda calculus because it can't express unbounded recursion - which is needed for `map`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off,

> everything in Haskell is λ-calculus

This is not really correct. Haskell has lots of features that don't correspond to something in untyped λ-calculus. Maybe they mean it could be *compiled* to λ-calculus, but that's kind of obvious, what with “any Turing-complete language...” jadda jadda.

> What is λ expression for a higher order function like `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`

There are two unrelated issues here. The “higher order function” part is no problem at all for a direct λ translation, and as the comments already said

```
($) = \f -> \x -> f x   -- λf.λx.fx
```

or alternatively

```
($) = \f x -> f x
($) = \f -> f  -- by η-reduction
```

(which in Haskell we would further shorten to `($) = id`).

The other thing is that `map` is a recursive function defined on an algebraic data type, and translating that to untyped λ-calculus would lead us quite far away from Haskell. It is more instructive to translate it to a λ-flavour that includes pattern matching (`case`) and `let`-bindings, which is indeed essentially what GHC does when compiling a program. It's easy enough to come up with

```
map = \f l -> case l of
               [] -> []
               (x:xs) -> f x : map f xs
```

...or to avoid recursing on a top-level binding

```
map = \f -> let go l = case l of
                        [] -> []
                        (x:xs) -> f x : go xs
            in go
```

We can't get rid of the `let` just like that, since λ-calculus doesn't directly support recursion. But recursion can also be expressed with a fixpoint combinator; unlike in untyped λ-calculus, we can't define the Y-combinator ourselves but we can just assume [`fix :: (a -> a) -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:fix) as a primitive. That turns out to fulfill almost exactly the same job as a recursive let-binding, which is then immediately evaluated:

```
map = \f -> fix ( \go l -> case l of
                            [] -> []
                            (x:xs) -> f x : go xs )
```

To make up a λ-style syntax for this,

```
map = λf.fix(λg.λl.{l? []⟼[]; (x:s)⟼fx:gs})
```

Answer (score 2):

(*warning:* the following code contains an error, leading to the definition which results in the equation `map f (x:xs) == f x : map f (map f xs)`, as far as I can tell.)

---

Continuing on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62185062/849891) by [@leftaroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745903/leftaroundabout),

```
MAP = λf.Y(λg.λl.l(NIL)(λxs.CONS(fx)(gs)))
```

**Y** is a fixed-point combinator:

```
Y = λg.(λx.g(xx))(λx.g(xx))   -- Yg == g(Yg)

-- MAP(f) == (λl.l(NIL)(λxs.CONS(fx)(MAP(f)s)))
```

Lists are lambda terms that accept two arguments to be applied appropriately, first in case the list is empty, second if not:

```
-- constructs an empty list
NIL = λnc.n

-- constructs a non-empty list from its two constituent parts
CONS = λadnc.ca(dnc)
```

Thus e.g. a term returned by `CONS(1)(CONS(2)NIL)` will be transformed by `MAP(f)` to

```
MAP(f)(NIL)nc -> (NIL)nc -> n
MAP(f)(CONS(2)NIL)nc -> CONS(2)NIL(NIL)(λxs.CONS(fx)(MAP(f)s))nc
                     -> (λxs.CONS(fx)(MAP(f)s))(2)(NIL)nc
                     -> CONS(f(2))(MAP(f)(NIL))nc
                     -> c(f(2))(MAP(f)(NIL)nc)
                     -> c(f(2))((NIL)nc)
                     -> c(f(2))n
MAP(f)(CONS(1)(CONS(2)NIL))nc ->
                     -> CONS(1)(CONS(2)NIL)(NIL)(λxs.CONS(fx)(MAP(f)s))nc
                     -> (λxs.CONS(fx)(MAP(f)s))(1)(CONS(2)NIL)nc
                     -> CONS(f(1))(MAP(f)(CONS(2)NIL))nc
                     -> c(f(1))(MAP(f)(CONS(2)NIL)nc)
                     -> ....
                     -> c(f(1))(c(f(2))n)
```